# how to use AWS + Serverless Framework + Credentials + MFA on Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm currently using an Ubuntu virtual machine where NODEJS and the Serverless Framework are up and running. I've been deploying a container image as a Lambda function using the 'sls deploy' command, and it's been working fine on the Ubuntu VM. However, there have been occasional issues with boot errors on the VM since it's running within a virtual machine environment.

My AWS user has Administrator privileges, and Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) is enabled.

Now, I'd like to set up Serverless and perform 'sls deploy' from my Windows 10 machine. Nodejs and Serverless are already installed on my Windows machine.

Could you please guide me on how to set up Serverless, log in with MFA, and perform 'sls deploy' on my Windows 10 machine?

Thank you!